# Include cell value in SUM only if corresponding cell has certain text value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've made a table that helps me manage outstanding payments due (i.e. money that I owe) to another company.

This table has two columns, the first entitled '**Total Due**', the second entitled '**Paid?**'. I have a few rows for invoice totals owed and whether or not they've been paid yet. A brief example is below (please forgive the terrible attempt at creating a table - this form is pathetically strict on HTML usage!):

|**Total Due** |---- **Paid?** --|

|-- £20 ----|---- (Blank) --|

|-- £40 ----|---- YES -----|

|-- £25 ----|---- (Blank) --|

|-- £32 ----|---- YES -----|

I want to **only** SUM the **'Total Due**' payments that **haven't** been paid (the ones that have a corresponding '(Blank)' cell in the '**Paid?**' column) - i.e. IF the corresponding cell in the '**Paid?**' column has the text 'YES', **don't** include the '**Total Due**' amount in the sum.

In this example,  I **first** want the formula to check if any cells in the '**Paid?**' column have the text 'YES' in them. As two of them do, I **then** want the formula to **only** SUM £20 and £25.

I've tried this formula so far, but as you can see, it's very long and repetitive, and doesn't fully work:

```
=IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES",E13="YES",E14="YES",E15="YES",E16="YES",E17="YES"),0,IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES",E13="YES",E14="YES",E15="YES",E16="YES"),D17,IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES",E13="YES",E14="YES",E15="YES"),SUM(D16,D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES",E13="YES",E14="YES"),SUM(D15:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES",E13="YES"),SUM(D14:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES",E12="YES"),SUM(D13:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES",E11="YES"),SUM(D12:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES",E10="YES"),SUM(D11:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES",E9="YES"),SUM(D10:D17),IF(AND(E7="YES",E8="YES"),SUM(D9:D17),IF(E7="YES",SUM(D8:D17),SUM(D7:D17))))))))))))
```

As you can see, this formula only works as long as you enter 'YES' in order downwards (i.e. if you enter 'YES' in the first corresponding cell, THEN the second corresponding cell, etc.). If you leave the first corresponding cell blank then enter 'YES' in the second corresponding cell (for the second payment), the formula ignores it and SUMS all '**Total's Due**'.

Comment: You need `sumif` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that: `=SUMIF(E7:E17,"YES",D7:D17)`, but it does the opposite; it only SUMS the corresponding value IF there's a "YES" in the '**Paid?**' cell.

Comment: is number text or a value with £ prefix in format. must be extracted if so

Comment: @Raystafarian that did it! Duh! I feel stupid now. Tried a variety of IFs, SUMs and SUMIFs but I think I was trying too hard! Also I assumed Excel would ignore the speech-marks if no text was entered.

Comment: Yeah, it's not great practice to use `""` but we don't have many options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sumif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) is what you want to use:

```
=SUMIF(E7:E17,"",D7:D17)
```

Comment: Err:508 in Open Office which uses semi-colons                             =SUMIF(Range; Criteria; SumRange)

Comment: @TonyStewart I didn't see an open office tag.

Comment: I was trying to make it work in OO but couldn't even with ; it gave 0 result

Comment: OO worked with "YES" but not "".. quirks of compatibility

Answer (score 0):

In Open Office - it looks like SUMPRODUCT is a workaround for the quirk of a blank criteria in SUMIF.

See [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=29928).

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you actually show a solution using SUMPRODUCT, and describe when or why you would use that rather than SUMIF.

Answer (score -1):

If the formula =SUMIF(E7:E17,"",D7:D17) doesn't work try switching the places of columns to =SUMIF(D7:D17,"",E7:E17)